# How can I remove the stop words from sentence using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, tr

I'm trying to remove stop words from sentences in file?

Stop Word which I mean :
`[I, a, an, as, at, the, by, in, for, of, on, that]`

I have these sentences in file `my_text.txt` :

> One of the primary goals in the design of the Unix system was to
> create an environment that promoted efficient program

Then I want to remove stop word form the sentence above

I used this script :

```
array=( I a an as at the by in for of on that  )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
cat $p  | sed -e 's/\<$i\>//g' 
done < my_text.txt
```

But the output is:

> One of the primary goals in the design of the Unix system was to
> create an environment that promoted efficient program

The expected output should be :

> One primary goals design Unix system was to
> create an environment promoted efficient program

Note: I want to Delete Remove stop words not duplicated words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, assuming `$p` is an existing file:

```
 sed -i -e "s/\<$i\>//g" "$p"
```

You have to use double quotes, not single quotes to get variables expanded.

The `-i` switch replace *in line*.

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

## Finally

```
array=( I a an as at the by in for of on that  )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    sed -i -e "s/\<$i\>\s*//g" Input_File 
done
```

## Bonus

Try without `\s*` to understand why I added this regex

Comment: When I used the above script, there is no output shown? Are you sure the code or script is correct?

        `array=( I a an as at the by in for of on that  )
        for i in "${array[@]}"
        do
        sed -i -e "s/\<$i\>//g" my_text.txt 
        done`

There is no output shown and the output is  : 
>  ~/project$ ./remove.sh   
>  ~/project$

Comment: Yes, the file is modified: `cat my_text.txt`

Answer (score 1):

One in awk. It's a working prop but needs proper punctuation handling and then some (then again luckily your data had none):

```
$ awk '
NF==FNR {                         # process stop words
    split($0,a,/,/)               # comma separated without space
    for(i in a)                   # they go to b hash
        b[a[i]]
    next
}
{                                 # reading the text
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)            # iterating them words
        if(!($i in b))            # if current word notfound in stop words
            printf "%s%s",$i,OFS  # output it (leftover space in the end, sorry)
        print ""                  # newline in the 
}' words text
```

Output:

```
One primary goals design Unix system was to create environment promoted efficient program
```

Why awk? Shell is a tool for managing files and launching programs. All apart that are better handled elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Can used this script :

```
while read p 
do 
  echo $p | sed -e 's/\<I\>//g' | sed -e 's/\<an\>//g' | sed -e 's/\<a\>// g'|sed -e 's/\<as\>//g'|sed -e 's/\<at\>//g'|sed -e 's/\<the\>//g' | sed -e 's/\<by\>//g' | sed -e 's/\<in\>//g' | sed -e 's/\<for\>//g' | sed -e 's/\<of\>//g' | sed -e 's/\<on\>//g' > my_text.txt
  
  cat my_text.txt

done < my_text.txt
```

Then the output it must like this :

> One primary goals design Unix system was to create an environment promoted efficient
> program

Answer (score 0):

I am also very fond of using awk in text processing. Assuming the input data is the `mytext.txt` file, and `script` is the file containing the code below, simply run it as `awk -f mytext.txt script`.

Also, this should make it easier to change the stop words when needed, by changing the `stopwords` variable. Keep in mind both `mytext.txt` and `stopwords` must contain only space separated words.

```
BEGIN {
stopwords = "I a an as at the by in for of on that"
split(stopwords, wordarray)
ORS = " "
RS = " "
}

{
equals = 0
for (w in wordarray)
  if ($0 == wordarray[w])
    equals = 1
if (equals == 0) print $0
}
```