# Change a letter in a file to uppercase in Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to change a specific given letter to uppercase in a file, but I don't know how to do it. The file already exist and I want to do the following

```
cat merry.txt 
I wish you a Merry Christmas
```

Change e to E so the output will be

```
cat merry.txt
I wish you a MErry Christmas
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: This should do the trick: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20414/find-and-replace-text-within-a-file-using-commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
sed 's/e/\Ue/' Input_File
```

To edit permanently, add `-i` switch:

```
sed -i ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know if it works for a first command line argument passed to myshell, for example is I create a script called upper and I execute it ./upper e

Comment: For sure, why not ? The way to thanks here is accepting answer/voting answers.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry but I've trying with (./upper e) sed 's/$1/\U($1)/g' filename.txt and it doesn't work

Comment: Exactly the issue someone get some minutes ago, see quoting issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/65331815/465183

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
sed 's/e/E/' merry.txt
```

If your text included more than one occurrence of ”e” on a line, the preceding sed would
have changed just the first occurrence on each line to ”E.” By appending the global option
`g` to the end of the s command, you can ensure that multiple occurrences of the string on a line will be changed.

Try to use this :

```
sed 's/e/E/g' merry.txt
```

This command converts all `e` to `E`.

Or can use :

```
sed -i 's/e/E/g' merry.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tr` to "translate" a char to another char:

```sh
tr 'e' 'E' < file > newfile && mv newfile file
```

You can also use `awk` (here, a dynamic approach is used):

```sh
find='e'
replace='E'
awk -v f="$find" -v r="$replace" '{gsub(f, r)}1' file > newfile && mv newfile file
```

With GNU `sed`, you may use

```
sed -i 'y/e/E/' file
```

In all these case, you replace an `e` with `E` everywhere in the file and save the contents of the updated file under the same filename.

See a [sample demo online](https://ideone.com/lHXTm0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='I wish them a Merry Christmas'
find='e'
replace='E'
tr "$find" "$replace" <<< "$s"
awk -v f="$find" -v r="$replace" '{gsub(f, r)}1' <<< "$s"
sed 'y/e/E/' <<< "$s"
```

Output: `I wish thEm a MErry Christmas`.